# Problems with routes and CakePHP 2.2.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2

I have installed CakePHP on windows over II7 and i am having problems with the routes.
I have created a Model, a Controller and a View for **Users**.

When i try to access the index view, i do it like this without any problem:

```
http://myhost/cakephp/users/
```

But, when I try to add a new user, the view doesn't load properly:

```
http://myhost/cakephp/users/add/
```

It shows this error:

```
Error: AddController could not be found.
Error: Create the class AddController below in file: app\Controller\AddController.php
```

In order to make it work, i have to do this in *app/Config/routes.php*:

```
Router::connect('/users/add', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
```

But that wouldn't be necessary if it worked well.
Neither the *delete* or *view* views load.

What's going on? How can i detect the problem?
Thanks.

## EDIT

Content of routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/', array(
    'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'
));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array(
    'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'
));
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Comment: Post all content of `routes.php`.

Comment: I have updated the post with it.

Comment: Have you done this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#url-rewrites-on-iis7-windows-hosts ?

Comment: Yeah, i have done it. The problem stills the same plus CSS styles doesn't load. So I added another rule as detailed on here: http://www2.palomar.edu/pages/sphillips/cakephp-with-iis-7-rewrite-rules-in-a-sub-folder/

Comment: Ok, it seems i have solved it. It was all because of adding a routing prefix using cake bake console... I had to comment this line at core.php //Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('users'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems i have solved it. It was all because of adding a routing prefix using cake bake console... I had to comment this line at **core.php**

```
 Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('users'));
```